# Font Aliasing in oracle forms 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-apps

I am setting a font type  of a button to Calibri in oracle forms 11g but it is changing to Arial at runtime. In oracle forms help I saw about font aliasing but I don't know where to find the font aliasing file.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the link [Font Aliasing in Oracle11g Forms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e24479/pbr_font004.htm#RSPUB23185)

Comment: It is giving font aliasing for reports. I am facing problem in oracle forms.

Comment: Well i dont think you can do any font aliasing in Oracle forms. its applicable to reports only. See below doc on oracle forms `https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10240/basics.htm#FSDEP523`